# duplicate value store in database like adding new row on on click

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

i work on database application store data like image on oncreate method of application now problem is every time i launch app there add multiple duplicate values in my database table so help me about this problem

my db class

```
package handler;

import java.sql.Blob;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import property.property;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class handler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    static String Database_Name="image5.db";
    String Table_Name="img_demo";
    String Image="image";
    String ID="id";
    String Image_Name="image_name";
    String Web="website";
    String Image_No="image_no";


    public handler(Context context)
    {
        super(context,Database_Name, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL("create table img_demo(id integer primary key autoincrement,image_name text,website text,image_no integer,image blob)");

    }

    public void insertdata(ArrayList<String> str1,ArrayList<String> str2,ArrayList<Integer> no,ArrayList<byte[]> im)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sd=getWritableDatabase();
        for(int i=0;i<str2.size();i++)
        {
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();


            String nm=str1.get(i);
            String web=str2.get(i);
            int no1=no.get(i);
            byte[] img=im.get(i);


            cv.put(Image_Name, nm);
            cv.put(Image_No, no1);
            cv.put(Web, web);
            cv.put(Image, img);

            sd.insert(Table_Name, null, cv);
        }
        sd.close();

    }



public ArrayList<property> show() 
{
    SQLiteDatabase sd=getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=sd.query(Table_Name, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    ArrayList<property> ap=new ArrayList<property>();
    property p;

    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
        p=new property();
        int id= c.getInt(0);
        String nm= c.getString(1);
        byte[] b=c.getBlob(4);
        p.setId(id);
        p.setName(nm);
        p.setImage(b);

        ap.add(p);






    }
    return ap;
}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

mainactivity class

    enter code here

package com.example.imagetextfromdbex;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;



import property.property;

import handler.handler;
import android.R.integer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnok;
    private ImageView img;
    private TextView txt;


    ArrayList<String> imagename=new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> web=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> no=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<byte[]> image1=new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    ArrayList<Integer> imag=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        imagename.add("Image1");
        imagename.add("Image2");
        imagename.add("Image3");

        web.add("web1");
        web.add("web2");
        web.add("web3");

        no.add(1);
        no.add(2);
        no.add(3);

        imag.add(R.drawable.icon1);
        imag.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        imag.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        handler h=new handler(this);


        for(int i=0;i<web.size();i++)
        {
            Bitmap image=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imag.get(i));
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,bos);
            byte imageinbyte[]=bos.toByteArray();

            image1.add(imageinbyte);


        }
        h.insertdata(imagename,web,no,image1);

        btnok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnok);
        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        btnok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<Integer> aid=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                handler hd=new handler(MainActivity.this);
                ArrayList<property> p=hd.show();

                StringBuffer sb;
                for(property p1 : p)
                {
                    sb=new StringBuffer();
                    int id=p1.getId();
                    String name=p1.getName();
                    byte[] image=p1.getImage();
                    sb.append(name).append("\n");
                    ByteArrayInputStream boi= new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
                    Bitmap image1=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(boi);
                    img.setImageBitmap(image1);
                    ar.add(sb.toString());
                    aid.add(id);
                }

            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Everything on UI thread, use CurorLoaders or AsyncTask, dont kill your application, and during insert check for duplicates by querying the db, and matching with image name field.

Comment: but fist time add 3 row and then when m relaunch the application there add more 3 row as same values

Comment: Fisrt remove these db insert calls from UI thread, then edit your question, then we will see.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding something to the database, first check if that entry already exists. In this way , you can avoid duplicity.

**EDIT**: To check for duplicate entries in the database, use this code

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper2.getReadableDatabase();
boolean exists=false; //Boolean flag to check if current entry is duplicate
String sortOrder2 =  Tablename._ID;

        Cursor c = db.query(
                DbName.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
                projection2,                               // The columns to return
                null,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                                     // don't group the rows
                null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
                sortOrder2                                 // The sort order
                );

        //For each entry currently found, check if it already exists in the database

        c.moveToFirst();
        //check if entry is already present in db or not

        for(int entry_num=0;entry_num<c.getCount();entry_num++)
        {

            if(current_entry.equals(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Table Name.Column name in table)))) //current_entry may refer to name or some property of the new entry. Check that with the corresponding entry in the database, as per your requirement
            {
                exists= true;
                break;
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }  
        c.close();

    if(exists)
    {
           //Don't add to database
    }
    else
    {
          //Add to database
    }
```

Add this code wherever your main new entry scan and adding to database is done.

**Note**: DbName, mDbHelper, Table Name, Column name : These you should change as per your requirement.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: how to check exist data in the table like database on upgrade method @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Name);
  
 }

Comment: check my edit: Note that some of the names are not actual variables but names I have given so you can understand

Comment: You don't need to drop the table, just check for entry if duplicate, don't add ( as I have mentioned in my answer).